# watir-webdriver - execute_script throws javascript error

Tags: javascript, ruby, watir-webdriver

Below javascript code fetches the id and inner text of all the div elements starting with "opt1". I am doing this with javascript because this divs are invisible and webdriver doesn't support accessing invisible elements.

The below code works fine when executing on irb but fails with a "JavaScript error" when I run the whole script. I also executed the javascript code on the IE Console to make sure that javascript is correct and their were no errors.

```
   mn = $browser.execute_script <<-JS
   var eles = window.frames[1].document.getElementsByTagName('div');
   var dom = [];
   for ( var i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
     if (eles[i].id.indexOf("opt1_") === 0) {
       dom.push(eles[i].id + "--" + eles[i].innerText);
     }
   }
   return dom;
   JS
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely with the way that Selenium handles frames. It looks like the Javascript error will occur when trying to do anything with a frame - ie the error occurs due to:

```
window.frames[1].document
```

**Solution - Execute Javascript in context of the frame**

One solution is to run the Javascript in the context of the frame.

Assuming that the main page is using iframes (though similar can be done with frames):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="test.htm"></iframe>
    <iframe src="frame_content.htm"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the frame_content.htm has some visible and non-visible divs:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>irrelevant content</div>
    <div id="opt1_visible">visible content</div>
    <div id="opt1_hidden" style="display:none;">hidden content</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in Watir, you can execute the script (modified to remove `window.frames[1]`) against the frame object (instead of the browser):

```
frame = browser.iframe(:index => 1) # Use .frame if the page is using frames instead
mn = frame.execute_script <<-JS
   var eles = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
   var dom = [];
   for ( var i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
     if (eles[i].id.indexOf("opt1_") === 0) {
       dom.push(eles[i].id + "--" + eles[i].innerText);
     }
   }
   return dom;
   JS
p mn
#=> ["opt1_visible--visible content", "opt1_hidden--hidden content"]
```

**Solution - Using just Watir**

While Watir cannot perform actions on invisible elements, you can still inspect them. The only difficult one is getting the text since Element#text only returns visible text. The workaround is to use `Element#attribute_value` instead.

You can get the same results as the Javascript approach by doing:

```
frame = b.iframe(:index => 1) # Use .frame if the page is using frames instead
mn = b.divs(:id => /^opt1_/).map do |div|
  "#{div.id}--#{div.attribute_value('innerText')}"
end
p mn
#=> ["opt1_visible--visible content", "opt1_hidden--hidden content"]
```

Note that `.attribute_value('innerText')` works in IE. If you are using Firefox you will need to do `.attribute_value('textContent')` instead. I believe Chrome supports both attributes.